Computing Tangent and Normal Space of a Submanifold of $m \times n$ matrices having rank $r$.
I have come up with the following problem in my assignment
The set $X=\{A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}):\mathrm{rk}(A)=r\}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Also, given any $A\in X$, compute its tangent space and normal space.
I can solve the first part of the problem by using permutation matrices and Schur's complement. But I am stuck with the second part of the problem, where I am asked to compute its and tangent space and normal space.
I would also like to ask if anyone can summarize a useful algorithm for tangent space and normal space computation in case of matrices, as I am facing a lot of problem coming up with a unique way to solve each matrix related problem that I face.

If a submanifold of condimension $k$ is locally given by a system of $k$ defining equations, then you are reduced to a linear algebra question. If you have a $k\times \ell$ matrix $C$ of rank $k$, then look at its nullspace (kernel) and the orthogonal complement of the nullspace, i.e., the row space.

Yes, that I have done but I wanted some more explicit form of the tangent and normal spaces, which I am unable to get, as in I wanted to like sort of get the basis of these spaces, or I want to check if they belong to some special matrix space or not.
